# CRUD operation using MongoDb and Asp.net Core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

I am new in mongoDb, thats why I want to make a CRUD operation using mongodb and asp.net core. Below is my code from google. In UpdateStudent function "string body" pass as a parameter. But I want to pass an object named "Student oStudent". How can I do it?

```
   public async Task<UpdateResult> UpdateStudent(string id, string body)
    {
        var student = Builders<Student>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, id);
        var update = Builders<Student>.Update
                                    .Set(x => x.Body, body);
        return await _context.Students.UpdateOneAsync(student, update);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this;

```
await _context.Students.ReplaceOneAsync(doc => doc.Id == student.Id, student);
```